# No repetir etiqueta SQL

Tags: sql

[image: Tengo el siguiente caso]

Es una consulta de dos tablas diferentes. La tabla amarilla es la principal donde tengo *kilos pedidos por producto*. Y la tabla verde donde utilizo un `left join` para traerme lo *facturado*.

Hay un mismo producto *facturado* con dos lotes diferentes, la `MTDELA`, y por ende me trae *kg pedidos (20)* dos veces.

¿Es posible que en el query no se me repita etiqueta y me lo traiga como el ejemplo 1, o que haga un conteo y me lo traiga como el ejemplo 2, para que la suma de 20?

```
Select Productoped, Kg pedidos, Kg facturados
FROM TABLAPEDIDOS
LEFT JOIN TABLAFACTURA ON (Productoped= productofac)
```

Comment: ¿En qué motor trabajas? muestra cómo están los datos en las tablas de origen.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: El ejemplo1 es imposible. SQL (en cualquier motor) no soluciona problemas de visualizacion.. muestra filas de a 1 tal cual lo que le pedis. Para el ejemplo dos, se necesitaria saber los datos de origen para ver si es posible.

Comment: ok  podemos sumar 9 + 11 en Kg facturados, pero que pasa con el campo "Lote" , que descripción de lote (L0002 y L0003) vas a mostrar en el resultado?

Comment: No se puede si quieres mostrar ambos lotes.

Answer (score 0):

Hola desconozco los campos de tu otra tabla pero yo pensaria en usar una funciones de agregado y realizar una agrupacion de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT Productoped, SUM(Kg pedidos), SUM(Kg facturados)
FROM TABLAPEDIDOS
LEFT JOIN TABLAFACTURA ON (Productoped= productofac)
GROUP BY Productoped, Lote
```